# Are Pop Fisher and The Judge brothers?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-natural

[The Natural](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087781/) is one of the greatest sports movies of all time. There are some artful mysteries in this film and one of them might be: *Are Pop Fisher and The Judge brothers?*

The biggest clue is this line:

> Pop: "Red, did you talk to that bastard brother of mine about the
> water?"
>
> Red: "Judge says he's workin' on it, Pop."